# Azure web service is not working properly

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

For several days I am experiencing that Azure Web Services is receiving many requests in seconds. Due to this Website is not able to load.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Do you have a virtual network? Do you have firewall configured?

Comment: Also, are the requests that your Azure Web Services are receiving from legitimate users or programs?

Answer (score 0):

> Since many days I am experiencing that Azure Web Services is receiving many requests in seconds.

You could check the request logs by enable Web Server Logging in Azure Portal. By researching the log, you could know whether the requests are from legitimate users or programs. If they are from trusted users or programs, you could [scale up or out your web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-scale) to meet the large number of requests.

If the requests are from attackers, you could block these kinds of requests by configuring Dynamic IP Address Restrictions(DIPR). The DIPR feature provides two main protections for developers:

1. Blocking of IP addresses based on number of concurrent requests
2. Blocking of IP addresses based on number of requests over a period of time

For more information, link below is for your reference.

[Configuring Dynamic IP Address Restrictions in Windows Azure Web Sites](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/confirming-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions-in-windows-azure-web-sites/)

If IP addresses of the requests are stable, you can also block these addresses or a range of IP addresses using ipSecurity configuration. For more information, link below is for your reference.

[IP and Domain Restrictions for Windows Azure Web Sites](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/ip-and-domain-restrictions-for-windows-azure-web-sites/)